# create a slide scrolling series of panels

Tags: android, user-interface

I am writing my first Android app.
The app is displays bus stop information i want to have a panel for each stop that the user can scroll sideways through, like a weather app with a panel for each city.
Looking at the Dev Guide I don't see how to do this.
What Layout Object/ViewGroup should I be using? or should i looking somewhere else?

Comment: This depends on the number of panels you'd like to display side-by-side. Do you want to just load them once into memory for a given city?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a [`HorizontalScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html). There's an example of its usage [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-horizontalscrollview-example/).

Comment: Thanks for that is there any best practice method of using that to create window sized panels? I'm still not sure how to make the panels but I can see how HorizontalScrollView could be used to scroll some kind of view